# How do I implement a Flutter text field with mentions, considering user IDs and duplicate display names?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've been cracking my brain over how to implement a flutter input text field that can allow mentions. Mentions in themselves are not too hard to implement with a custom TextEditingController, but the problems start showing up when you want to store the user id in the final message and allow mentioning users who have the same display name, as well as allowing edits after the message was written.

Every implementation I try I run into one issue or another, especially when you consider the user id and conflicting display names.

The goal: Create a text field that allows mentioning a user, even if another user has the same name, and allow the writer of the message to edit the message later on, keeping the mentions intact.

The goal in a list;

- Support mentioning a user from a list
- Support storing the user id in the final message because usernames can change
- Support mentioning users who have the same display name
- Support editing the message later on, keeping the mentions intact
- Support mentioning the same user in the message more than once
- Support editing in the middle of the message you're typing (you may not always type at the end of the message)

You can compare it to virtually any chat software out there (slack, discord, mattermost, etc).

I've seen a lot of packages out there that handle mentioning but none that handle conflicting display names, and none handling editing the message afterwards.

I've tried to look at how it's implemented in other frameworks/languages but I didn't find much that I was able to translate into the flutter framework.

Any help here is appreciated, thanks for your time!

Comment: For anyone else wondering how to do this, I created a package that meets all my requirements and published it to pub dev: https://pub.dev/packages/simply_mentions

Answer (score 0):

I just spent the last couple days trying to add mentions in my Flutter app, and it was not as straightforward as I thought, but I got it working. I might write up a medium post about it since there were a lot of nuances, but I will try to summarize the high level points in this answer.

The only requirement I did not meet that you listed is common display names. In my app (Whiskey Story), I have three identifiers for a user: user_id, username, and display_name. Of the three, user_id and username are required to be unique, so I just used the username for the mention text. You might be able to modify my approach to work with duplicate Display Names, but I am not sure how you would do that. Hopefully my approach still helps you out.

First, I found a github repo called [cr_mentions](https://github.com/Cleveroad/cr_mentions) that provided some insights on how to implement mentions. Overall, I ended up having different requirements, so I could not use the code, but it is worth a look.

Before I get into the high level steps, the format I ended up using for storing the mentions is:

`<@!user_id|username>` (e.g. <@!yPG7qzRZzrcqPZ1lAzlCeZooHOs4|craxiomdev> )

I am honestly not sure if this is a good format, but it seems to be working so far.

High level steps:

1. Extend TextEditingController
   Create a custom TextEditingController so that you can perform custom logic in the controller (e.g. add text change listener so you can watch for the `@` symbol). It sounds like you figured this part out, so I won't go into any detail on it.
2. When constructing the TextEditingController, pass in a ValueNotifier<Mention?> so that you can receive callbacks everytime the text change listener picks up the start of a mention. In the callback query the backend for a list of matching users and display them in an `OverlayEntry` that is anchored on the text field. If you want a code example for this comment on my post and I will share mine.
3. When the user clicks on a user from the Overlay list, call a method in the custom controller (e.g. `_mentionTextController.insertMention(mentionData);` that provides the user details such as user_id and username.
4. In the `insertMention` method, store the mentionData in a data structure so that you can retrieve it later, I stored it in `Set<MentionData> _mentionDataSet`. The MentionData object will have all the user details you care about, user_id, username, display_name, etc. Also in `insertMention`, add the text you want the user to see. I added `'@${mentionData.username}` as the display text.
5. Once the user goes to submit a whiskey review in my app, I then call a helper method to create the text that contains the user_id and username for each mention. Well, it is actually two steps. First, I call a method to find all the `@username` instances in the text, and then populate them into a `List<MentionModel> mentions`. The `MentionModel` contains the start and stop index of the mention in the String. I also set the username and user_id in the MentionModel. To set the user_id I iterate over the Set to find a matching username, which provides me access to the user_id. Since my usernames are unique, this works for me. You might need to do something else here since your display names are not unique. Now that I have the List that contains all the locations of the mentions in the text, I call getBackendText to generate the text that has the user_ids in it. See the method below.

```dart
  static String getBackendText(
      String currentText, List<MentionModel> mentions) {
    // Sort mentions by locationStart to handle them in order
    mentions.sort(MentionModel.sortMentionsByLocationStart);

    final StringBuffer newText = StringBuffer();
    int lastEnd = 0;

    for (final mention in mentions) {
      if (mention.locationStart != null &&
          mention.locationEnd != null &&
          mention.id != null &&
          mention.username != null) {
        // Add text before the mention
        newText.write(currentText.substring(lastEnd, mention.locationStart));

        // Add the mention in the new format
        newText.write('<@!${mention.id}|${mention.username}>');

        // Update the last processed end position
        lastEnd = mention.locationEnd!;
      }
    }

    // Append any remaining text after the last mention
    if (lastEnd < currentText.length) {
      newText.write(currentText.substring(lastEnd));
    }

    return newText.toString();
  }
```

6. When I want to render the text in the UI, I use a custom widget that takes the text, and a `List<MentionModel> mentions` (which you can come up with by parsing the backend text using a regex... see the getCodedMentionsFromText method below). Using the text and the list of mentions you can render them however you want using a TextSpan. The `cr_mentions` github repo provides a good example of that.

```dart
  static List<MentionModel> getCodedMentionsFromText(String text,
      {String tag = kAtSymbol}) {
    final pattern = RegExp(r'<@!(.*?)\|(.*?)>');
    return pattern.allMatches(text).map((e) {
      final userId = e.group(1)!;
      final username = e.group(2)!;

      return MentionModel(
        id: userId,
        username: username,
        locationStart: e.start,
        locationEnd: e.end,
        tagType: tag,
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

So to summarize:

1. The text editing controller stores the text and two collections (one for the user_id and username mapping, and another for all the mentions in the text, including the start and stop index and username).
2. When the user goes to submit the content to the server, the UI text is modified under the hood to include the the user_id.
3. When rendering the text in the UI, you modify the text under the hood again but this time you remove the user_id and just display the username (but I keep the user_id around so that when the mention is clicked on it navigates to the user profile).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I actually ended up making a pub package for it with my own solution and published it: https://pub.dev/packages/simply_mentions.

There's some caveats that I don't see mentioned in your answer, but things such as pasting text in front of the mention would offset so you need to listen to that as well.

Comment: Nice, I am glad you wrote up a package. I have it all working in my app, but now I am interested to try your package to see if it offers any benefits. One that I see is that you took the time to render the mention properly in the text editing controller, where I just left the normal text and mapped it to the final format on submission.